# Wondering what is wrong with this Declaration as opposed to the commented in code ? - Beginner here

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, c-strings, string-literals

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *s1 = "Hello";  /* Code doesn't work with this declaration instead works with char s1[] = "Hello"; */

    char *s2 = "world"; 

    strcpy(s1,s2);

    printf("copied is %s into %s",s1,s2);

    return 0;
}
```

Aren't char *s1 and char s1[] declarations same ?

Comment: Please format your code correctly (i.e. put triple backticks on a line before the code and on a line after the code).  You can use the preview feature to make sure your question or edit looks good before submitting it.  Currently, some of the asterisks in your code are disappearing and being interpreted as italic text by Markdown.

Comment: *Aren't char *s1 and char s1[] declarations same?* No they are not.  *If `s1` is a function parameter*, they are the same, but that is a very specific exception, and it is an exception, not a general rule.  If you have a book or other reference telling you that `char *s1` and `char s1[]` declarations are the same all of the time, burn it.

Answer (score 4):

> Aren't char *s1 and char s1[] declarations same ?

The declaration

```
char *s1 = "Hello";
```

declares a pointer to a string literal. You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal like for example that

```
strcpy(s1,s2);
```

results in undefined behavior.

This declaration

```
char s1[] = "Hello";
```

declares a character array elements of which are initialized by elements of the string literal.  The above declaration is equivalent to

```
char s1[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

You may change the character array because it is not declared as a constant array.

So this call of `strcpy` is correct for the array

```
strcpy(s1,s2);
```

You could also write for example

```
char s1[] = "Hello";
char *p = s1;
//...
strcpy(p,s2);
```

because in this case the pointer `p` does not point to a string literal. It points to the non-constant character array `s1`.

And the message in the call of printf

```
printf("copied is %s into %s",s1,s2);
```

is wrong. Actually this call

```
strcpy(s1,s2);
```

copies characters from `s2` into `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

> Aren't char *s1 and char s1[] declarations same ?

No.

```
char *s1 = "Hello";
```

declares `s1` as a pointer - all it stores is the *address* of the string literal `"Hello"`:

```
    +–––+
s1: |   | ––––––––––+
    +–––+           |
     ...            |
    +–––+           |
    |'H'| <–––––––––+
    +–––+
    |'e'|
    +–––+
    |'l'|
    +–––+
    |'l'|
    +–––+
    |'o'|
    +–––+
    | 0 |
    +–––+
```

The behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal (such as with `strcpy(s1,s2);`) is *undefined* - your code may crash outright, or it may just fail to update the string, or it may work as expected.

The declaration

```
char s1[] = "Hello";
```

allocates an array of char large enough to store the string `"Hello"` and initializes it with that string:

```
    +–––+  
s1: |'H'|
    +–––+
    |'e'|
    +–––+
    |'l'|
    +–––+
    |'l'|
    +–––+
    |'o'|
    +–––+
    | 0 |
    +–––+
```

This is an actual array that you can modify.  It can’t store any strings longer than `"Hello"`, but otherwise you can modify it to your heart’s content.